# Using resources of composite components from an external JAR

Tags: jsf, resources, jar, jsf-2, composite-component

I am using my composite components in an external jar-archive. In my jar-archive i have resources like images and css-files. For example, one of my components uses a button with an image inside. 
when i try to use my component in another project, the resource for the image is not found.

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`ResourceHandler`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) api. Check [this article](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#resource-loading).